# Global exception handler (access violations) under Windows

Tags: c, windows, exception, access-violation

I'm trying to install some sort of first-chance exception handler which can resume execution after unprotecting (`VirtualProtect()`) the memory page.

(I'm trying to install some watchpoints; and no, the possibility of the VirtualAlloc function to set watchpoints is *not* what I need; there I cannot dynamically set and unset the watching state of memory regions/pages)

I've read in the last couple of days a lot about these SEH things, but actually most I can find is for setting function local exception handlers etc....

If I'm not wrong I need to set somehow something called `FS[0]` (which is thread-local?).

---

#### tl;dr

I'd like to know how to install a global first-chance (= possibility to resume code and retry last instruction) exception handler which can catch hardware exceptions (like access violations).

P.s.: I can use Assembly, C or C++, but no C# etc.

---

Note: I have the whole thing working under POSIX systems via sigaction on SIGSEGV, but there's no such thing for Windows as far as I can see…

Comment: @pmg actually I see access violations being called `hardware exceptions`... (under windows)?

Comment: I kinda had a 2nd feeling about this midway through my comment, so I didn't remove the tag myself (comment removed).

Comment: @pmg MSVC can use `__try {...} __except(...) {...}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY correct, but that doesn't help as I want a global handler which can resume at the precise position where it failed.

Comment: @bwoebi So what are enclosed in `__try{}` the inside of the `main`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, but then the stack is already unwound and I cannot continue there where it failed?!

Comment: Can not continue to be resumed by `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` because modification of the code can not be.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Huh? a) I'm not modifying my code, just wanting to use VirtualProtect to change memory protection and b) you mean `ExceptionContinueExecption`?

Comment: i mean that Resume can be by `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`. But It cause an exception situation again, so has not changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int xfilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *xp) {
    int rc;
    EXCEPTION_RECORD *xr = xp->ExceptionRecord;
    CONTEXT *xc = xp->ContextRecord;
    if(xr->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION) {
        ++xc->Eip;//Advanced by one(Probably xc->Eip += 2)//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679284(v=vs.85).aspx
        rc = EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    } else {
        rc = EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    }
    return rc;
}

int main() {
    EXCEPTION_POINTERS * xp;
    char *p = NULL;
    __try {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "before\n");
        *p = 'X';//Access Violation
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "after\n");
    }
    __except(xfilter(xp = GetExceptionInformation())) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Exception occurred\n");//NO EXECUTE WHEN EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION
    }
    return 0;
}
/* result
before
after
*/
```

Comment: Is it that…? then I might have a bit misunderstood the docs… I'll try that.

Comment: As asked I want to get the address of the memory location where writing has been tried (to unprotect that page). I don't find such a thing in the EXCEPTION_RECORD or CONTEXT structs or am just unable to indentify the right field?

Comment: @bwoebi ; It may be seen that or tried to access the address of where the state of CONTEXT, but I do not know well to me.

Comment: Ah, I found it in a wall of text, thank you anyway! In EXCEPTION RECORD -> ExceptionInformation -> "The second array element specifies the virtual address of the inaccessible data."

Comment: sure , `xr->ExceptionInformation[1]` : `NULL` //Address of trying to access

Comment: Yes, that's what I found… I just pushed what I achieved now with your precious help :-) https://github.com/krakjoe/phpdbg/commit/3fcdd6ab0f8537d49019cbd01809c6a40a869f37